# Using PowerShell, copy files from the Share folder and upload them to the Azure git repo using CICD pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, cicd

I need assistance in creating a PowerShell script that would upload any files from any share folder to the existing Azure git repo using CICD pipeline. Please accept my apologies for requesting assistance from Scratch.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi @Bharath, have you check the answer below. Share folder to the existing Azure git repo by using powershell task. If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two powershell task to upload files from share folder to the existing Azure git repo using CICD pipeline. Here is the detailed steps.

Use the first powershell task to clone your repository to the local with the script as below. `cd` to a folder to do this operation, for example: `Pipeline.Workspace`. Clone your remote repo that you want push the files to.

```
cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)
git config --global user.email "<email address>"
git config --global user.name "<Name>"
git init .
git clone https://<username>:$(password)@dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<ProjectName>/_git/<repoName>
```

[image]

Then, copy files from shared folder to the local repo:`$(Pipeline.Workspace)/<repoName>`.

[image]

Finally, push the files to your git repository using another powershell task with the script below.

```
cd $(Pipeline.Workspace)/<repoName>
git add .
git commit -m "first commit of my code"
git remote add origin https://<username>:$(password)@dev.azure.com/<orgName>/<ProjectName>/_git/<repoName>
git push origin <branchName>
```